# ActionBar won't disappear

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I am trying to remove my ActionBar from only one page on my app. I have put in

```
NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False"
```

In hopes to remove the action bar as it is quite annoying and is not needed on this activity.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: If you want disable the navigation bar add this NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);

Comment: If you do not know which place could set these codes, you could refe to this link.https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/navigation-in-xamarin-forms/